# Differential geometry text with categorial flavor

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, book-recommendation

I am blown away by exposition of analytic manifolds in Serre's *Lie algebras and Lie groups*, I want more! Is there a text that treats classic topics of differential geometry like connections, Riemannian metrics, holonomy, de Rham cohomology, (almost) complex manifolds, homogeneous spaces, symmetric spaces in such a manner? Or maybe some more analytic manifolds, towards the modern research topics?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14877/how-much-of-differential-geometry-can-be-developed-entirely-without-atlases-clo

Comment: @RyanBudney, IMHO getting rid of atlases is not imperative, both Serre and Lang kept them in their respective texts and it was fine.

Comment: Warner's Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups emphasizes the structure sheaf approach. I found this to be quite amazing to read after I had the basics down (from John Lee's books). It isn't quite what you're looking for and doesn't do most things that differently, but worth a look in my opinion.

Comment: Oops. I should have clicked that link before commenting. I guess that is basically what the old post was about.